# Handling a create action with Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

It's been a while since I have done anything with Rails and UJS (especially the Ajax side of things).

I would like to be able to create an object with ajax and handle any validation errors that may arise.

So I start off with my form (using remote: true) `documents/new`

```
<% form_for @document, remote: true do |f| %>
 <!-- form fields and submit button here -->
<% end %>
```

Controller (this is where I'm a little stuck)

This is what I have now and below this is what I think it should be

```
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @document = current_user.documents.new(document_params)
  if @document.save
    redirect_to public_index_path, notice: 'Successfully Saved File'
  else
    render template: 'public/index'
  end
 end
end
```

Controller to handle ajax

```
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
  @document = current_user.documents.new(document_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @document.save
      format.html { redirect_to public_index_path, notice: 'Successfully Saved Document'}
      format.js { # Does anything need to be here?}
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.js { render json: @document.errors }
    end
  end
end
```

Within my views I have `documents/new`. Do I need a corresponding .js.erb file to accompany this?

As normally I remember that file would look something like

```
$('#idOfElement').html("<%= j render(:partial => 'shared/my_partial') %>")
```

### Update

At the moment I am getting a `template is missing` for create action error

My controller currently looks like this

```
def create
@document = current_user.documents.new(document_params)
respond_to do |format|
  if @document.save
    format.html { redirect_to public_index_path, notice: 'Successfully Saved File' }
    format.js { }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.js {  }
  end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `create.js.erb` file in `views/documents/` that will handle the js code that you need to run and place the new record on page, talking about rendering the partial.

So for example you have a list of documents on your page:

```
<div id="docs_list">
  <% @docs.each do |doc| %>
    <div id="doc#{doc.id}" class="document_item">
     ... doc content here
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

your `create.js.erb` file we'll have something like this:

```
<% if @document.valid? %>
  $("#new_document")[0].reset(); // this will reset the form
  $('.document_item').last().after('<%= j(render @document) %>'); // this will add the document to the list
<% else %>
  alert("Sorry, can not save document!");
<% end %>
```

Alos make sure you have `_document.html.erb` in `views/documents`.

Comment: thanks, for some reason i thought i needed corresponding new.. not getting an error now :)